# Open files in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, file, qt-creator

I want to:

1. when the user pick up a file from `QFileDialog`,
   I want the name of the file appeared in the `QLineEdit`
   and any info I want to show like size & type, etc.
   [image: see this image]
2. a way to take the user's files (Like `cin` in C++)
   so I can control this info or put it in Read file function

I searched everywhere in the web
but they talk in general not in detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <QApplication>

#include <QFileDialog>

class Tester : public QWidget
{
 public:

   void openFile()
   {
       QFileDialog::getOpenFileName( this, tr("Open Document"), 
                                     QDir::currentPath(), 
                                     tr("Document files (*.doc *.txt);;All files (*.*)"), 
                                     0, QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog );

       QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName( 
       this, 
       tr("Open Document"), 
       QDir::currentPath(), 
       tr("Document files (*.doc *.rtf);;All files (*.*)") );

       if( !filename.isNull() )
       {
           qDebug( filename.toAscii() );
       }
    }

   void openFiles()
   {
      QStringList filenames = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames( 
       this, 
       tr("Open Document"), 
       QDir::currentPath(), 
       tr("Documents (*.doc);;All files (*.*)") );

      if( !filenames.isEmpty() )
      {
         qDebug( filenames.join(",").toAscii() );
      }
    }

    void openDir()
    {
      QString dirname = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory( 
         this, 
         tr("Select a Directory"), 
         QDir::currentPath() );

       if( !dirname.isNull() )
       {
          qDebug( dirname.toAscii() );
       }
     }
}
```

Here is the source :  [Open File Dialog](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Cpp/Qt/Openfiledialogdemo.htm)

Comment: thank you soooooooooo much for your post, and sorry for troubling you thank you thank you

Answer (score 0):

> 1. when the user pick up a file from `QFileDialog`, I want the name of the file appeared in the `QLineEdit` and any info I want to show like size & type, etc.

To get file information of the selected file, you can use [`QFileInfo`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html).

```
// Absolute address of the selected file
QString file = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open file");

// Object for getting file info
QFileInfo info(file);

// File name
info.fileName();

// File owner
info.owner();

// File size
info.size();

// etc
```

> 2. a way to take the user's files (Like cin in C++) so I can control this info or put it in Read file function

I can't understand what you mean.

Comment: thank you so much, i really troubled you too don't bother about my question it's required to master Qt but i will tell you just to know, i wanted a method or a way to track any operation in Qt 
so i can use this info in another places i want like the QFileDialog & QLineEdi,  thank you again